# Compare mean of subsamples between groups

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, statistical-power, weighted-mean, friedman-test

I am going to collect quantitative data for two groups that I would like to compare. I have done a two sample t-test on some preliminary data and found a significant difference, but I don't think that is the best (or at least not the only) test I should use because each group is composed of multiple subjects that each have multiple measurements of the dependent variable, and I have reason to believe (based on plotting the frequency distributions by subject) that the measurements of the dependent variable vary by subject as well as between groups. I don't think this is a case of repeated measures because the measurements for any given subject are all collected at the same time.

An analogous situation would be if I wanted to compare the size of apples between two species of apple tree, so I measured the weight of multiple apples from multiple trees of both species. I want to compare the weights between species while accounting for the possibility that the weights vary from tree-to-tree within a species. I am having trouble figuring out the best test to use and what sample size I need, both how many trees per species and how many measurements per tree. Also, the number of measurements per tree will vary, so that's another reason why pooling all of the measurements by species and using a two sample t-test is not ideal--a tree with more apples measured will be over-represented in the pooled mean. I would like to figure out the minimum number trees and the minimum number of measurements per tree I need, but still be able to use every measurement collected per tree in cases where I can get more than the minimum number.

I think the pooled measurements for each group will probably be normally distributed, but based on my preliminary data, the measurements within a subject may not be. I won't know for sure until I have more data, though, as my preliminary data are pretty sparse. Based one what I read, I think that if I had more than two groups then I should use a two-way ANOVA or Friedman test (depending on normality), and look at the interaction between subject and group. I may want to compare >2 groups in the future, but for now I only have 2 so I don't think that will work. Do I need to use linear regression? Neither of the independent variables (group and subsample) are quantitative so I'm not sure how to go about that. Or maybe I should calculate the mean within each sample and then use a t-test to compare the means by group, and then use a separate test to look at variation by sample within a group?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It sounds to me that you're essentially working with a cluster sample. So for calculating the sample size necessary to achieve a particular power, you'll need to take the design effect into consideration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_effect

Comment: Sorry, I realize that's not what you were asking about, i.e. you've already done the sample. Anyhow, approaches to working with a cluster sample should be what you're looking for.